# Material angular infinite scroll with $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using `md-virtual-repeat` directive of `Angular Material` to have an infinite scroll, and I need to replace it's [demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) $timeout function with a $http request. But I can't get to the right solution. 
In the code below, infinite scroll works fine but doesn't show the data from http request. The problem is that I don't know the way of binding $http result to **infiniteItems**.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/86RihvKMsB1BYdHGYwTH) is the plunker.

**Index.html**

```
<body ng-app="infiniteScrolling" class="virtualRepeatdemoInfiniteScroll">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak>
    <md-content layout="column">
        <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container" flex>
            <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.infiniteItems" md-on-demand
                 class="repeated-item" flex>
                {{item.id}}
            </div>
        </md-virtual-repeat-container>
    </md-content>
</div>
</body>
```

**JS**:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
  .module('infiniteScrolling', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function ($timeout,$scope,$http) {
     this.infiniteItems = {
          numLoaded_: 0,
          toLoad_: 0,
          items:[],
          getItemAtIndex: function (index) {
              if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
                  this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
                  return null;
              }
              return index;
          },
          getLength: function () {
              return this.numLoaded_ + 5;
          },
          fetchMoreItems_: function (index) {
               if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
                  this.toLoad_ += 20;

                  $http.get('items.json').success(function (data) {
                      var items = data;
                      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                          this.items.push(items[i].data);
                      }
                      this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
                  }.bind(this));
              }
          }
      };
   });
})();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one works:

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/e32qVQ4ECZBleWq2Gb2O?p=preview)

- getItemAtIndex returned the index and not the item
- if you inspected what you pushed, you'd see that at line 33 in my plunkr I concat `obj.data`, not plain `obj`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('infiniteScrolling', ['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
          // In this example, we set up our model using a plain object.
          // Using a class works too. All that matters is that we implement
          // getItemAtIndex and getLength.
          var vm = this;
          vm.infiniteItems = {
              numLoaded_: 0,
              toLoad_: 0,
              items: [],

              // Required.
              getItemAtIndex: function (index) {
                  if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
                      this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
                      return null;
                  }
                  return this.items[index];
              },

              // Required.
              getLength: function () {
                  return this.numLoaded_ + 5;
              },

              fetchMoreItems_: function (index) {
                  if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
                      this.toLoad_ += 5;
                      $http.get('items.json').then(angular.bind(this, function (obj) {
                          this.items = this.items.concat(obj.data);
                          this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
                      }));
                  }
              }
          }
      })
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, It works. But I don't know why for  toLoad_+=20 , when I go down the scroll the data loads with a big delay, very down never loads not the same for toLoad_+=10 .

Comment: Well, actually it creates element in the DOM but since your api returns 5 elements, iirc, it has not enough data to initialize, so they are blank/empty.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I just wants to add one more point: I think replacing `data` with `obj.data` is not part of the solution as I was using `success` instead of `then` and it returns data not result, but using `concat` is part of the solution. Because when I remove that the code not work correctly. It has a downside as it store all data (all out of view data) in memory not only the data in view.

Comment: @A.M About the `success` vs `then` solution I presented: `success` and `error`have been [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: This actually works for me, except that I would want the list to stop scrolling once all the data is displayed. This solution repeats the json.data from the start again.

Comment: anyone figure out how to stop the scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

On every api call try to get wheather the db has few more records or not.
and add that condition in fetchMoreItems_ function.

```
fetchMoreItems_: function (index) {
              if (this.toLoad_ < index && hasMoreRecords) {
                  this.toLoad_ += 5;
```

In our code we get the details like

- sCurrentPage : 3
- sMore: true    ==>>this indicates that the db has more records or not after 
                    fetching page wise data.
- sTotalPages: 4
- sTotalRecords : 36

Comment: And your saying it creates element in the DOM and if we get lesser records that shows blank records. So how can I remove or stop generating those blank records. Can you please help...

Answer (score 0):

came here and saw @alessandro-buggin answer which was very helpful.
I had to change it a little bit, so I thought of sharing it for others to help. I needed:

- to avoid getting scroll requests while already recovering data (using `this.hold`)
- stopping requests when the whole data was received from the backend (using `this.stop_`)
- hiding the content while loading, to avoid glitches or empty elements (again using `this.hold`). On the view you need to use `ng-hide` on that element because `ng-if` avoid the element to ever exist so it won't load the first time.
- implementing a refresh method to reload data when parameters/filters changed from an outside form.

Far from perfect but works pretty well.

```
vm.elements = null;
vm.infiniteItems = { // Start of infinte logic

stop_: false,
hold: false,
numLoaded_: 0,
toLoad_: 0,
items: [],

refresh: function() {
    this.stop_ = false;
    this.hold = false;
    this.numLoaded_ = 0;
    this.toLoad_ = 0;
    this.items = [];
},

getItemAtIndex: function (index) {
    if (!this.hold) {
        if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
            this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return this.items[index];
},

getLength: function () {
    if (this.stop_) {
        return this.items.length;
    }
    return this.numLoaded_ + 5;
},

fetchMoreItems_: function (index) {
    if (this.toLoad_ < index) {

        this.hold = true;
        this.toLoad_ += 5;

        var start = this.numLoaded_;
        if (start > 0) start++;

        MyService.getData(parameters)
         .then(angular.bind(this, function (obj) {

          if (obj && obj.elements > 0) {
            vm.elements = obj.elements;
            this.items = this.items.concat(obj.data);

            if (obj.elements < this.toLoad_) {
                this.stop_ = true;
            }
            this.numLoaded_ = this.items.length;
            this.hold = false;

          } else { // if no data
            vm.elements = 0;
          }
        }));
    }
}

} // End of infinte logic
```

Note: my service returns an object composed like this:
`obj = {elements: INTEGER, data: ARRAY}` where elements tells you the length of the full query.