# Is there a way to refresh virtual repeat container?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I've got a `md-virtual-repeat-container` that handles the data from an API call triggered by a search box. I'd like to be able to refresh this container when a user enters a *second* search query.

I'm using a setup similar to this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/e32qVQ4ECZBleWq2Gb2O?p=preview) which is from [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759185/material-angular-infinite-scroll-with-http-request). The only difference is its getting data from a server when the user enters a search term.

### My Question

Is there a way to trigger a refresh an `md-virtual-repeat-container`?

---

I don't think the code is relevant but here's my (simplified) production code:

```
    var self = this;
    self.infiniteItems = {
        numLoaded_: 0,
        toLoad_: 0,
        items: [],
        getItemAtIndex: function (index) {
        if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
            this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
                return null;
            }
            return this.items[index];
         },
         getLength: function() {
            return this.numLoaded_ + 25;
         },
         fetchMoreItems_: function (index) { 
             if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
                 this.toLoad_ += 5;
                 var offset = 0;

                 $http({
                     method: 'GET',
                     datatype: 'json',
                     url: '{my-api-call}',
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     cache: false,
                     params: {
                         param: query,
                         page: offset
                     }
                  }).then(angular.bind(this, function (obj) {
                     this.items = this.items.concat(obj.data.SearchResults);
                     this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
                     this.offset++;
                     $scope.searchResults = obj.data.SearchResults;
                  }));
             } 
         }
    };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can force a redraw of your md-virtual-repeat container by triggering a fake window resize event (this causes the directive to call its private `handleScroll_()` method which then calls `containerUpdated()`).

This will trigger a fake window resize event:

```
angular.element(window).triggerHandler('resize');
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, if it works out I'll select your answer as the solution. thanks

Comment: finally a great answer, honestly wish there was a cleaner solution, in my case I had to wrap $timeout to wait for tabs to finish changing and then re-draw

Comment: You just saved my $#! ^^.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this to cause refresh of items in specific scope and not in the entire document:

```
scope.$broadcast('$md-resize')
```

Answer (score 2):

Resetting the model should also work.

In your case you could a have a new function on *infiniteItems*:

```
refresh : function() {
            this.numLoaded_= 0;
            this.toLoad_ = 0;
            this.items = [];
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post my solution since there isn't an answer yet. If an better answer gets posted I'll gladly accept it.

**First**, I migrated all of my search result code into it's own template, directive and controller.

**Next**, I added an empty container in place of my logic. I'll use this as a place to dump my directive dynamically every time I search.

```
`<div id="search-result-container"></div>`
```

**Finally**, I dynamically appended my new directive like this

```
$scope.handleHotlineSearchClick = function () {           
    var query = $('#legal-search-input').val();

    if (query != "") {
        $scope.searchLoaded = false;
        $('#search-result-container').empty().append($compile("<search-result></search-result>")($scope));
    }
};
```

This way every time the user enters a new search term the directive gets reloaded.